# How can I find image points for given world points in Halcon using a line scan camera?

Tags: coordinates, halcon

In Halcon with a line scan camera, I've got my image points to world points with the command `image_points_to_world_plane`. But is there a inverse, so if I have the world points that I can get the image points of those?

I've tried pose_to_hom_mat3d and from this I've tried project_point_hom_mat3d. But I was expecting some coordinates, but I don't know how further. And I don't know what I need to put on the z-coordinate.